# detection of bootstrap navbar links fails with slim

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, slim-lang

In my rails app, styled with bootstrap3, I decided to switch Slim instead of existing ERB. While I was converting erb view files to slim, I've noticed that styles of navbar links were disappeared.

```
# app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.slim
nav.navbar.navbar-default
  .container
    .navbar-header.navbar-left
      button(type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse")
        span.sr-only Toggle navigation
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
      a.navbar-brand href="/" Foody

    .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-right#bs-navbar-collapse
      ul.nav.navbar-nav
      - if user_signed_in?
          li = link_to current_user.email, edit_user_registration_path
          li = link_to 'New Recipe', new_recipe_path
          li = link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?"
      - else
          li = link_to 'Sign In', new_user_session_path
          li = link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path

      span.clearfix
```

Here is the original file I've converted from:

```
# app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.erb
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Foody</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to current_user.email, edit_user_registration_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'New Recipe', new_recipe_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?" %></li>
        <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to 'Sign In', new_user_session_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the result both normal & responsive modes

[image]

Here's output (sorry for complexitie)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul><li><a href="/users/sign_in">Sign In</a></li>
<li><a href="/users/sign_up">Sign Up</a></li><span class="clearfix"></span>
```

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you share the generated html before/after where the problem occurs?

Comment: @GraemeMcLean question is updated

Comment: Thanks - is this from ERB or Slim?  We really need to see both, and for you to show where the difference is.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean the output is from Slim, but as I've seen that `li`s under `ul.nav.navbar-nav` are in same level, not under `ul` as it should be. That's the problem, probably...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation failure bagan after `ul.nav.navbar-nav` caused the problem. Need more practice for Slim. Special thanks for Graeme!

```
nav.navbar.navbar-default
  div.container
    div.navbar-header.navbar-left
      button(type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse")
        span.sr-only Toggle navigation
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
      a.navbar-brand href="/" Foody
    div.collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-right#bs-navbar-collapse
      ul.nav.navbar-nav
        - if user_signed_in?
          li = link_to current_user.email, edit_user_registration_path
          li = link_to 'New Recipe', new_recipe_path
          li = link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?"
        - else
          li = link_to 'Sign In', new_user_session_path
          li = link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path
    span.clearfix
```